# asp repeater populated with datatable not displaying

Tags: asp.net, repeater, sqldatareader

I'm trying to use a asp repeater for the first time. I used the following tutorial as a guide:
http://www.sitepoint.com/asp-net-repeater-con

My problem is that the asp repeater is not showing on the page. not even the header or footer.

As seen below I have a data table that is populated with a SqlDataReader. I bound the table to the asp repeater.

Function called after a button click event that does an ajax call to my code behind:

```
function getRangeList() {
   var vardateRange = { dateStart: $("#dateStart").val(), dateEnd: $("#dateEnd").val(),   MethodName: 'getRangeList' }
   var options =
      {
         url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Default.aspx") %>',
         async: true,
         data: vardateRange,
         dataType: 'text',
         type: 'POST',
         success: function()  {
            alert("test");
         }
      }
      $.ajax(options);
      }

      C# code:    
 protected void getRangeList()
    {
       using (SqlConnection connRangeList = new SqlConnection(this.strOwanConnString))
          {    
             SqlCommand cmdRangeList = new SqlCommand("[some_sp]", conn1);
             cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
             cmd1.Parameters.Add("@somevalue", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = x;
             conn1.Open();
             SqlDataReader dt1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
             repeater1.DataSource = dt1;
             repeater1.DataBind();
           }
     }
```

aspx page:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeater1" runat="server">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                Test<table border="1">
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "patientID")%></td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                </table>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

I'm assuming I have a very basic misconception of the functions and call I'm making. Please help me clear this up. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem was structure related. The function getRangeList was not executed at pageload. therefore causing the bind event for the repeater to bind. I placed the binding function in my page load and it worked like a champ.